# rasterio mask fill nodata with np.nan: TypeError: Cannot convert fill_value nan to dtype uint8

Tags: python, rasterio

I'm facing troubles while reading a raster dataset having `uint8` value when trying to fill the nodata gaps with `np.nan`.

The following function works like a charm for opening a GeoTIFF DEM (having floating values) but not when opening a GeoTIFF ortho image (having `uint8` values on the RGB channels because the `dtype` statement is simply ignored when in `read` mode (see the doc hereunder):

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.features import shapes
from rasterio.mask import mask
print(rasterio.__version__) # 1.3a3

with rasterio.open(
    raster_file,
    mode='r',
    driver='GTiff',
    dtype='float32'
) as src:
    raster_t, _transform = mask(
        src,
        shapes=[shape],
        all_touched=True,
        invert=False,
        nodata=np.nan, # <- if I remove this line everything goes well
        filled=True,
        crop=True,
        pad=False,
        indexes=None
    )
```

```
TypeError: Cannot convert fill_value nan to dtype uint8
```

How could I get it to work for both cases? I was not successfully to gather the dtype information of the open dataset `src` in order to test for it.

> dtype (str or numpy dtype) – The data type for bands. For example: ‘uint8’ or rasterio.uint16. Required in ‘w’ or ‘w+’ modes, it is ignored in ‘r’ or ‘r+’ modes.

Doc: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.html?highlight=open#rasterio.open

Comment: Check this code:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/426542/197892